# CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Entity'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to save a ManagedObject to a property for use within a static framework

```
@interface Descriptor : NSObject

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObject *managedObject;

@end
```

I assign it in the project I am using the framework on and it immediately on load crashes the app. with

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Entity'
```

The 'Entity' is a simple Managed Object I setup in the project and I am assigning it like so

```
Descriptor *descriptor = [[Descriptor alloc] init];
descriptor.managedObject = [[Entity alloc] init];
```

Any pointers are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the reply but those fixes on those pages dont apply to me I have tried them before asking this question! please read the question and or understand it before commenting

Comment: Please read the other answers and fix `[[Entity alloc] init];`

Comment: *"those fixes on those pages dont apply to me"*: they probably do. –  *"I have tried them before asking this question"*: show what you have tried and what did not work. – *"read the question and or understand it before commenting"*: read the other answers and understand them.

Comment: ok I blame monday! I have it working now you were right I shouldn't have been alloc. I changed the parameter to NSEntityDescription and assigned it as such so it does work I was just looking for something specific but it dint work.. thanks!